# JQuery Script not checking check-boxes correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two functions that I have made that check and uncheck all check boxes with a specific class. the first time I run the functions they do as expected but after I try to run the function again the check boxes do not check, but the html code changes.

JQuery...

```
function checkall() {
   $('.column').attr('checked','checked');
   $('#ALL').attr('onclick', 'uncheckall()')
   document.getElementById('ALL').value = "UnCheck All";
}
```

after running this I get `<input type="checkbox" value="SEQN" class="column" onchange="updatearray()" checked="checked">`

```
function uncheckall() {
   $('.column').removeAttr('checked');
   $('#ALL').attr('onclick', 'checkall()')
   document.getElementById('ALL').value = "Check All";
}
```

after running this I get `<input type="checkbox" value="SEQN" class="column" onchange="updatearray()">`

Why do the check-boxes only change once?

Comment: `$('#ALL').attr('onclick', 'checkall()')` isn't the proper way to add an event listener, if you're using jQuery then use it and don't do `document.getElementById('ALL').value = "UnCheck All";`, and `.attr('checked','checked')` should be `.prop('checked',true)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try prop() instead attr().If issue still persist iterate individual checkbox